# Redirect to previous page and display error in a alert box

Tags: php

In my project, the first PHP page takes input from user and submits it to the second PHP page. In the second PHP page, the values which come from first page are validated against values from database, using functions. I want to redirect to the first page if any of the values submitted  is wrong. Please help me out with the code. If not possible in PHP please mention the code in any other like jQuery or Ajax.

Comment: Look into using sessions and try to come up with a solution yourself. Asking for code from scratch without even supplying an example is not nice.

Comment: I need code for 'else' part of 'If Else' to redirect and display a message in previous page .

Answer (score 6):

Here is code that does exactely what you want (according to your title):

```
<script type="text/javascript">alert("Stupid message");history.go(-1);</script>
```

I don't like this way of working, you'd better to use sessions, or creating one file that displays the form and does the validating.

Answer (score 1):

@M LOHIT

```
 <script type="text/javascript">alert("Stupid message");window.location.href='previouspage';
    </script>
```

This will surely work for you

Answer (score 1):

```
echo"<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Data Failed');window.location.href='index.php';</script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

```
echo '<script>alert("your error message"); location.replace(document.referrer);</script>';
```